jq skip iteration over null
I am using jq 1.7
Data
I am operating on info.json downloaded by yt-dlp
yt-dlp --write-info-json --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlIO-7Rpi7c

JQ - Task

Now I want to remove all array inside subtitles whose name is not de, en-US and inside de, en-US select all objects with element ext == vtt.

This successfully works as follows:
jq 'pick(.subtitles | .de[],."en-US"[] | select (.ext == "vtt")) | del(..|nulls)' *.json

output
{
  "subtitles": {
    "de": [
      {
        "ext": "vtt",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=vlIO-7Rpi7c&ei=JS05ZoT2Ftf0i9oP8dy4mAo&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1715048341&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Cei%2Ccaps%2Copi%2Cxoaf&signature=AB2ECEEABF48D1A16ADC7ACCB8A072D63EE12DCC.5F56904251766FB68624A68FF2BBB57B9CCFFD2F&key=yt8&lang=de&fmt=vtt",
        "name": "German"
      }
    ],
    "en-US": [
      {
        "ext": "vtt",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=vlIO-7Rpi7c&ei=JS05ZoT2Ftf0i9oP8dy4mAo&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1715048341&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Cei%2Ccaps%2Copi%2Cxoaf&signature=AB2ECEEABF48D1A16ADC7ACCB8A072D63EE12DCC.5F56904251766FB68624A68FF2BBB57B9CCFFD2F&key=yt8&lang=en-US&fmt=vtt",
        "name": "English (United States)"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Issue
For some Youtube video, json file does not contain "en-US" but contain "en", while some contain all three of de, en, en-US. So I wrote the following
jq 'pick(.subtitles | .de[],.en[],."en-US"[] | select (.ext == "vtt")) | del(..|nulls)' *.json

Error
jq: error (at :69): Cannot iterate over null (null)
Help required
How to select only .ext == "vtt" for only language en,en-US,de if not all of these languages are present in the json file?

I would separate the pick() and the select() so that the correct languages are picked out first:
pick(.subtitles["de","en-US","en"])

Then, select only the elements of the arrays that have the correct ext value, skipping any null values:
.subtitles |= map_values(. // empty | map(select(.ext == "vtt")))

In the above, map_values() will apply the given expression to each key's value (and each key's value is an array).  With . // empty, any value that is logically false, such as null, is removed. The expression map(select()) will remove any array element not fulfilling the selection criteria.
Together:
$ jq 'pick(.subtitles["de","en-US","en"]) | .subtitles |= map_values(. // empty | map(select(.ext == "vtt")))' file
{
  "subtitles": {
    "de": [
      {
        "ext": "vtt",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=vlIO-7Rpi7c&ei=0kk5Zrz5N7W00u8P46eBkAg&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1715055682&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Cei%2Ccaps%2Copi%2Cxoaf&signature=6A7D608A8DBC357F885E4EFCA6282A52A52744B7.6F747CF42817EBAE27A98754FC69B5EA254F4D9C&key=yt8&lang=de&fmt=vtt",
        "name": "German"
      }
    ],
    "en-US": [
      {
        "ext": "vtt",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=vlIO-7Rpi7c&ei=0kk5Zrz5N7W00u8P46eBkAg&caps=asr&opi=112496729&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1715055682&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Cei%2Ccaps%2Copi%2Cxoaf&signature=6A7D608A8DBC357F885E4EFCA6282A52A52744B7.6F747CF42817EBAE27A98754FC69B5EA254F4D9C&key=yt8&lang=en-US&fmt=vtt",
        "name": "English (United States)"
      }
    ]
  }
}

This would also work if the subtitles object is empty or missing.

To leave the other top-level keys in place and only modify what's under subtitles:
.subtitles |= (pick(.["de","en-US","en"]) | map_values(. // empty | map(select(.ext == "vtt"))))

Notice how this is made up of the same basic components as the expression above, but here we modify subtitles in the original document while previously we modified subtitles in the "picked" document (a document where only subtitles and a number of its keys existed).

Additional (not requested in original post): Is it possible to put other elements of root object (i.e. other than subtitles) to be preserved? (in addition to above solution)

@Porcupine You mean to not remove all other top-level keys? Or do you want to select which ones to keep?

not remove top level keys other than subtitles while doing above filtering for subtitle language

for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehTIhQpj9ys the subtitle key is empty and your solution gives the error jq: error (at a.json:5848): Cannot iterate over null (null)

Could you please write why null is problematic but empty is not?

@Porcupine See updated answer.  null is a value, while empty is not a value. See the difference between jq -n 'null' (and jq -n 'null[]') and jq -n 'empty' (and jq -n 'empty[]').  The empty expression "does not exist".
